# parallel PowerShell jobs

Tags: powershell, jobs

I'm trying to run PowerShell jobs in parallel (500) but for some reason it seems most jobs run one after the other, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$jobs = {
    Param(
        [string]$thread_number_VDM,
        [string]$thread_number_FS
    )

    for ($i=1; $i -le 60; $i++) {
        #blablabla check something for 60 seconds
        # sleep 1
    }
}

###### main #####

for ($x=1; $x -le 50; $x++) {
    for ($z=1; $z -le 10; $z++) {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobs -ArgumentList ($x, $z)
    }
}
```

Comment: `powershell`, or `bash`? pick one. Or are you trying `ubuntu bash on win10`?

Comment: @anishsane The code is obviously PowerShell, so clearly not a bash question.

Comment: This question pops up every now and then. There does seem to be some kind of concurrency limit to background jobs, but I have been unable to find anything conlusive about it. With that said, I wouldn't recommend starting 500 jobs in parallel anyway. Use a job queue for throttling concurrency to a reasonable size.